# Ubuntu 17.10 How to move wokspace overview to the left (when you press Super+s)

Tags: gnome, workspaces, 17.10

When you press Super+S by default workspaces switcher appears on the right:

Current way:
[image]

I would really like to have it on the left instead:

Desired way:
[image: desired]

Reason: I multitask heavily and have 9-12 workspaces, constantly switching between them (5-10 times a minute), I've enabled left top corner to open the same thing as Super+S but have to move mouse through whole screen to switch to it, will save me 30 minutes a day if it would be possible to have workspaces on the left instead.